# How to get selected item count from custom listview in android

Tags: android

How to get selected item count from custom listview.

```
viewHolder.imgbtnp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                Product pp = productdata.get(position);
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (pp.getUserQty() < 10)
                        pp.setUserQty(pp.getUserQty() + 1);
                    productdata.set(position, pp);
             viewHolder.tv_qty.setText(String.valueOf(pp.getUserQty()));
                    ProductAdapter.this.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });

            viewHolder.imgbtnm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                Product pp = productdata.get(position);
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if (pp.getUserQty() > 0)
                        pp.setUserQty(pp.getUserQty() - 1);
                    productdata.set(position, pp);                            viewHolder.tv_qty.setText(String.valueOf(pp.getUserQty()));
                    ProductAdapter.this.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });

                  int totalCartValue = 0;
                    if (productdata != null && productdata.size() > 0) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < productdata.size(); i++) {
                            Product hi = productdata.get(i);
                  totalCartValue = totalCartValue +                            hi.getProductValue();
                        }
                           viewHolder.tv_value.setText("" + totalCartValue);
                       Log.d(Config.tag, "total cart size" +    totalCartValue);
                    }
```

Comment: whats the problem you are facing?

Comment: in my program it gives 0

Comment: print your getProductCount in for loop before if statement and in if statement check its value

Comment: Post some more detail/code

Comment: show us code of your multiselecttion.

Comment: it's not clear what you are asking, what is 0 ? also, all the time you are talking about `getUserQty()` then suddenly you call `getProductValue()` this does not make sense, we can't get into your mind and know what this method do, and what the other one does, so post a specific issue, and the related code, and make sure to make it clear